# Is there any way to manually modify the thresholds set in the decision tree learnt from a given dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I was trying to create a decision tree model using scikit-learn's module: `tree`. Once I generated the model, I visualized the tree and the criteria based on which the decisions were made. However, I wish to modify the thresholds in some criteria manually to see how the output changes for the same. Is there any method to do so? Or any library that converts the decision tree into a bunch of if-else statements once it has learned the required thresholds from the dataset and vice-versa?

I know that the thresholds chosen by the module are based on some impurity metrics like Gini-impurity, information gain, etc. However, I still would like to experiment with those threshold values.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont know if it is possible, but as you have the tree, you can implement it by hand (if its not gigantic) and modify the values there. However as the tree maximizes the metrics (either gini or infg) you wont find any "better" results using those metrics. In case you want to check with another metric, you can just use that metric to have a maximum value while creating the tree itself

Comment: You can try using GridSearchCV and provide whatever parameters that you want to experiment with. Take a look at it this link: https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-decision-trees/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do this.

A `sklearn` Decision Tree exposes its underlying tree through the `tree_` attribute. This `tree_`, among other things, have an attribute `threshold`, which is a numpy array containing threshold values of all nodes. You can modify this array, thereby changing the thresholds.

For example:

```
X,y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3).fit(X,y)
print(dt.tree_.threshold)     #All the thresholds, size equals "dt.tree_.node_count"
dt.tree_.threshold[3] = 10.0  #Manually modifying a threshold
```

To verify, If you compare accuracy on a seperate test set before and after this modification (assuming you've modified a non-leaf node), you should notice a change (which is likely to be worse).